# Monte Carlo simulation including gaussian elimination using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, performance, optimization, linear-algebra

I have written a code which solves a system of linear equations serval times in a row during a Monte Carlo simulation.

For each run the input is slightly changed and the solution must be calculated every time again. The purpose of this is to obtain the probability distribution function of the results (the solutions of the linear system).

So, my question is:
Is there a way to solve the system of linear equations only once and save the generic solution so that for every Monte Carlo run the solutions can be calculated directly?

This would be very time saving as for a proper simulation I need at least 20k runs and even for small systems of three unknowns this takes a long time. My code solves this linear equations every time new as in its original version the number of variables and therefore the number of input quantities should be closable and thus the generic solutions are unknow.

Here is my Gaussian elimination algorithm.

```
Function gaussian_elimination(w As Variant, mm As Variant, R As Variant, rb As Variant, n_iso As Integer) As Variant()

'initializing running indexes
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim h As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    n = n_iso

'runing variables for Gauss elimination
    Dim ip As Integer
    Dim q As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim z As Double
    Dim temp1(1, 1) As Variant
    Dim temp2(1, 1) As Variant
    Dim sum As Variant


'initializing b vector
    Dim b() As Variant
    ReDim b(1 To n - 1, 0 To 1)

'initializing k vector
    Dim k() As Variant
    ReDim k(1 To n - 1, 0 To 1)

'initializing A matrix
    Dim a() As Variant
    ReDim a(1 To n - 1, 1 To n - 1)

'initializing X matrix
    Dim x() As Variant
    ReDim x(1 To n - 1, 1 To n)


' calculating b vector

    For i = 1 To (n - 1) Step 1
        b(i, 0) = mm(1, 0) / (w(i + n - 1, 0) * (rb(i, 0) - R(i * n, 0))) - mm(1, 0) / (w(i, 0) * (R(i, 0) - rb(i, 0)))
    Next i

'calculating A matrix
    For i = 1 To (n - 1) Step 1
        For j = 1 To (n - 1) Step 1
            a(i, j) = mm(j + 1, 0) * ((R(j + i * (n - 1), 0) / (w(i + n - 1, 0) * (rb(i, 0) - R(i * n, 0)))) - (R(j, 0) / (w(i, 0) * (R(i, 0) - rb(i, 0)))))
        Next j
    Next i



    'using on board solving routine

    Dim A_Inv As Variant
    Dim k_vec As Variant
    Dim b_dummy As Variant





'filling X matrix
    For i = 1 To n - 1 Step 1
        For j = 1 To n Step 1
                If j = (n) Then
                    x(i, j) = b(i, 0)
                Else: x(i, j) = a(i, j)
                End If
        Next j
    Next i

   'Gaussian elimination
    For i = 1 To (n - 2) Step 1
        For j = i + 1 To (n - 1) Step 1
            If (Abs(x(j, i)) > Abs(x(i, i))) Then
                For h = 1 To n
                    temp1(1, 1) = x(i, h)
                    temp2(1, 1) = x(j, h)
                    x(i, h) = temp2(1, 1)
                    x(j, h) = temp1(1, 1)
                Next h
            End If
        Next

        For p = i + 1 To n - 1
            z = x(p, i) / x(i, i)
            For q = i + 1 To n
                x(p, q) = x(p, q) - z * x(i, q)
            Next q
            x(p, i) = 0
        Next p
    Next i






'calculatiing k factors backwards
    If Abs(x(UBound(x, 1), UBound(x, 2) - 1)) <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "Equation system can not be solved! Solving for k factors faild", vbExclamation, "Warning!"
        Exit Function
    End If

    k((UBound(x, 1)), 0) = x((UBound(x, 1)), UBound(x, 2)) / x((UBound(x, 1)), (UBound(x, 2) - 1))

    For i = ((UBound(x, 1) - 1)) To (LBound(x, 1)) Step -1
        sum = x(i, UBound(x, 2))
        For j = i + 1 To (UBound(x, 2) - 1) Step 1
            sum = sum - x(i, j) * k(j, 0)
        Next j
        k(i, 0) = sum / x(i, i)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To n - 1
        k(i, 0) = (-1) * k(i, 0)
    Next i

    gaussian_elimination = k



End Function
```

Comment: Of course it is possible, but Excel does it by default. Formula results are recalculated when input cells change, Excel is not always recalculating all data.

Comment: but how can I store the result, and reuse it with a different input?

Comment: I'm not realizing what you're trying to achieve: if input is different, output will be different, so, must be calculated, right?

Comment: Yes, a diffrent slightly different input results in a slightly different output.  For instance, we have the folllowing linear system:

x1 -a*x2+x3 =2 
x1+b*x2+c*x3=3
x1-d*x2+x3=1

x1 to x3 are the wanted quanteties that my code calculates. a to d depend on my input but for example for x3 one calculated a generic solution by substraction equation one from equation three. This means solving the linear system only once and not for any run.

Comment: Are you saying that you need to calculate a first run which generates intermediary values you would like to re-use for subsequent calculations so they don't need to be recalculated? These would have to be constant across inputs though.

Comment: I think the best would be you show a full [mcve] with proper example data so anyone can reproduce it.

Comment: Not realy intermediat values, more like generic symbolic solutions. for example, x3=a/b+c (I do not know if this is right but for the sake of simplicity let's assume it is right). Now having this generic solution all the code has to do is du varry a to d by varring my input. The input quanteties are normal distributed and also the standard deviation is given, so thta this is no problem.